# How do I catch XAML bugs before release?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, maui

We are having several issues where everything works ok on our local devices, but then crashes when we deploy release builds.

We have identified this is mostly caused by bugs in our XAML code.

I am guessing there is some difference with XAML in release vs debug build (possibly compilation?). The issue is debug seems to be more forgiving with problems, which means it is only after release that they come to light.

The problem is these bugs are very hard to find. The stack trace shows you nothing of value, so you need to keep doing repeated releases with additional error finding code which is immensely time consuming.

Does anyone know a) what is causing this, and b) what I can do about it to find these issues while debugging?

I have set this in App:
[assembly: XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]

I have also added this to the code behind (not sure I need to because of the above?):
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]

Should I be doing something else?

Thanks

Comment: You can run your code in release build, even on your own machine. Create PDBs for the release build so you can debug it. Check for binding issues etc. which are printed into some output window. Make sure that you actually deliver all DLLs in your setup and that they are put in the correct place. Do extensive testing before you ship to customers.

Comment: Can you give me example of one of those hard to find bugs, that manifest themselves only when in release mode?

Comment: You don't need to enable XAML compilation explicitly in MAUI, it's [enabled by default.](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/xaml/xamlc) You can safely get rid of those `[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]` lines. What kind of bugs are you talking about? Are you using compiled bindings? Do your bindings depend on asynchronously loaded data? Please show an example with code (XAML, code-behind and ViewModel) where such a problem occurs.

Comment: Here is an example. Someone did a copy/paste of a button into a ContentView and forgot to remove this: IsVisible="{Binding Source={x:Reference myView}, Path=ShowEditFunction}". The exception which started appearing was 'unable to figure out route for: //MyPage'. The exception gave very little clue to the problem.

Comment: On the point of running local release builds - I gave up trying that. The chance of getting a successful release build in VS is almost zero from my experience. In VS for Mac, it is actually zero. Are others not having the same problem? I should mention that these problems are largely related to iOS, although my above example also happened in Android.

Comment: @BuckBuchanan I am signing my release builds with dev. And I am deploying it with hot reload (VS for Win). How correct I am doing it is questionable. Then I am building it for store using production, using remote connection to  MAC, but putting it up in Test Flight first. This is release, but it is not so critical if something is not OK. And it is confirmed pretty fast, so you can make changes easily.

Comment: Btw, thank you for sharing this error about binding. It really seems like a nightmare, this message is light years away from being useful.